# Is Time Machine also backing up my Windows data from Bootcamp?

Tags: macos, time-machine, bootcamp

I don’t know how to check whether my windows data is included when I set up time machine. I would love an answer that explains how I could tell this if possible, but if not, the main question follows.

Does Time Machine back up Bootcamp data by default?

Answer (score 3):

No, the BootCamp partition is not backed up by Time Machine.

You'll need to install a separate backup system for that. Either a Windows backup systems running on Windows when you use that system, or a Mac backup system that supports the file system you've used for Bootcamp (usually NTFS).